# C Do loop misinterpreting conditions

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to run a do loop in c, but the conditions seem to be reversed. Here's my code:

```
#import <cs50.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Number: ");
    }
    while ((n < 23)&&(n >= 0));
    printf("%i\n", n);
}
```

If I input 52, it should re-prompt me, but it prints it. If I switch the first condition's operator to `>`, it re-prompts me. I then switched the second condition's operator to `>=`, and it printed any number. I may be misunderstanding the operators, but I've looked online and they seem to be right.

Comment: The first two lines should be `#include ...` not `#import`.

Comment: maybe you mentally imagine it as do...until, when in fact it is do...while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do { /* ... */ } while ((n < 23)&&(n >= 0));` this means do something in that block while `n < 23` and `n >= 0`.

> If I input 52, it should re-prompt me, but it prints it.

For `n == 52`, obviously `n < 23` is not satisfied, thus go out of this block and execute the `printf()`.